# using ng-src to display selected picture in an input file

Tags: angularjs

I have an input file as following :

```
<input id="identityDocument" name="identityDocument" ng-model="candidature.identityDocument"
                 ui-jq="filestyle" type="file" class="filestyle input-lg"
                 ui-options="{
                    buttonText: '{{'ACTIONS.UPLOAD' | translate}}',
                    iconName: 'fa fa-inbox'
                  }"
                 onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this,'identityDocument')"
                 accept="image/*" valid-file ng-required="identityDocument == null">
```

when I select a new file the `setFile` function is triggered and a scope variable named `identityDocument` will contain the loaded image.

After I load this image I preview it using this html code :

```
<img ng-src="{{identityDocument}}" class="md-card-image img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="{{'ERRORS.NO_PHOTO_SELECTED' | translate}}"></div>
```

this works, but when I select an image for the first time and then I open the select file dialog for the second time and then I click on Cancel instead of Open, I always see the image displayed even though that the `identityDocument` variable was set to null after I canceled the select dialog.

this is my `setFile` function :

```
$scope.setFile = function (element, name) {

      let reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (event) {
        $parse(name).assign($scope, event.target.result);
        $scope.$apply();
      };
      try {
        reader.readAsDataURL(element.files[0]);
      } catch (err) {
        $parse(name).assign($scope, null);
        $scope.$apply();
      }
    };
```

So how can I hide the image after the `identityDocument` variable was set to null ?

Comment: Does "cancelling" involve any async calls?

Comment: @AndrejBurcev I dont think so because I haven't done any treatments when I cancel the select dialog I just use that `setFile` function whenever I change the value of input file including the cancelling.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<img ng-src="{{identityDocument}}" ng-show="identityDocument" class="md-card-image img-responsive img-thumbnail" alt="{{'ERRORS.NO_PHOTO_SELECTED' | translate}}"></div>
```

Notice `ng-show` shows the element on truthy value and hides it on falsey value (null)

Comment: yes I tought about that, but in this case the message when there is no image selected will not be shown which is in here : `alt="{{'ERRORS.NO_PHOTO_SELECTED' | translate}}"`

Comment: so which of the behaviors do you want?

Comment: in the first time before I select any picture I can see the alternative message of the image which is `alt="{{'ERRORS.NO_PHOTO_SELECTED' | translate}}"` and  `identityDocument` variable is set to null, and after I select some image it will be displayed since `identityDocument` variable has the image to be displayed, but I want when I cancel the select file dialog to show the alternative message, this is not happening even though that identityDocument` was set to null after cancelling

Comment: Could you upload a plunkr?